# How do you remove parts of a string in a column using rstrip in Pandas?

Tags: python, string, pandas

Code before rstrip

```
column_names = lh_Area_Base_V2.columns.tolist()
for i, val in enumerate(column_names[1:]):
    column_names[i+1] += '_Base_V2'
column_names[0] = 'Subj_ID'
# Replace the column names with a new name
lh_Area_Base_V2.columns = column_names
lh_Area_Base_V2.head()
```

[image: Initial DF]

Code with rstrip (to drop "_V2" from the end of first column values):

```
column_names = lh_Area_Base_V2.columns.tolist()
for i, val in enumerate(column_names[1:]):
    column_names[i+1] += '_Base_V2'
column_names[0] = 'Subj_ID'
lh_Area_Base_V2['Subj_ID'] = lh_Area_Base_V2['Subj_ID'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip().rstrip('_V2'))
# Replace the column names with a new name
lh_Area_Base_V2.columns = column_names
lh_Area_Base_V2.head()
```

[image: Resulting DF After rstrip]

Error: Why does ID index #1 have a value 2 dropped at the end, which was not requested by the rstrip function (the function only requested for "_V2" to be dropped)?

I would love to hear any suggestions for fixes.

Comment: Please post dataframes as text, not images

Comment: `rstrip()` removes *any* from the character list, not *all*. For example `"Hello".rstrip('Ao2')` returns `'Hell'`.

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate since Pandas `str` method behaviour mimics exactly regular Python string methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior of [`rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

> The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed

It is not just stripping the *string* `_V2`, it will strip any of the contained characters, including the `2` at the end of your second row.

Instead, you may use a regular expression to replace a trailing `_V2`:

```
df.assign(Subj_ID=df.Subj_ID.str.replace(r'_V2$', ''))

    Subj_ID  lh_bankssts_area_base_V2
0  SILVA001                       861
1  SILVA002                      1051
2  SILVA004                      1127
3  SILVA005                      1346
4  SILVA007                      1209
```